# Unable to connect mainframe server from x3270if code

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Trying to connect mainframe using console app provided [here](https://github.com/davidkrider/x3270-x3270if-code), getting below error in the trace.

> SSL DLL init failed: Cannot load ssleay32.dll

Tried copying ssleay32.dll in bin folder but still getting the issue.

Please help me with this.

I am using a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your operating environment is Linux.  Make sure the LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the location of the dll you are loading.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:x3270ifInstallDir/bin

Replacing `x3270ifInstallDir/bin` with where your dll is located

Comment: Not linux, I am using windows machine